# Send post data from external web application to Laravel

Tags: php

I'm trying to send post data from an external application to my Laravel application.

I have a simple form on the www.myexternal.com. When I submit the form the from data are sent to the Laravel application on the web.

I receive the error:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException

I supposed it was due to the csrf and so I've added an exception in the VerifyCsrfToken.php but still not working.

**Here is the route in the web.php file:**

Route::post('/datasent', DataSentController@index');

**Here is the exception in the VerifyCsrfToke.php:**

```
protected $except = [
'datasent',
];
```

[The HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q02zi.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<form action="https://mylaravelapp.com/datasent" method="POST" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<div>
    <label for="xrc">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="text" id="xrc" name="xrc">
</div>
<div class="button">
    <button type="submit">Send message</button>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Could someone help me? I didn't find a solution and I should be able to send data. Is there something wrong in my code or this is not allowed by Laravel?

Comment: Show us your HTML form, does the `action` attribute has a trailing slash by any chance?

Comment: `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` means that you are trying to use a method that the route is not defined to. For example, you might be trying to GET on a POST route. Try adding your HTML form.

Comment: Don't paste code in the comments, please. Edit your question and paste it there. Thanks

Comment: Can we see your index controller code?

Comment: You should move it out of `web.php` into `api.php`. This bypasses the web middleware and CSRF stuff. Then change the form action to `https://mylaravelapp.com/api/datasent`

Comment: The index controller code it does not make sense in this phase. It contains a simple return to a view. I still didn't start to code it.
Dave, your suggestion makes sense and I made the changes but still the same error. Is there some config parameters I should change?

Comment: I have found the root cause of the issue. I had to change the URL in the form action, adding the www prefix:

From: https://mylaravelapp.com/api/datasent

to https://www.mylaravelapp.com/api/datasent

If I digit https://mylaravelapp.com I get forwarded to: www.mylaravelapp.com. It's not clear to me why this doesn't happen with the Laravel route.

Thanks for helping